# Link to emacs manual

Tags: org-mode

I would like to make a link in my .org-file that links to the builtin manual. I am writing myself a shorter manual snippets how to use Emacs.

For example:

```
For more information see [[whatever I need to type here][Dire-mode in Emacs manual]].
```

Pressing the link should leave me exactly where C-h f dired-mode RET leaves me. Is it possible and how do I write the "URL"?

Comment: which version of emacs are you using? I'm almost afraid to ask. You might even want to tell us which version of org-mode you are using, just in case not all versions have the same abilities.

Comment: Not at all a bad question. I should have included that from the start. Emacs is 24.4.1 and org version is 8.2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store a link to a help buffer by calling `org-store-link` in
that buffer and then going to your Org file and calling
`org-insert-link`.  This will prompt you for the link that you just
stored, and selecting it will insert the link as

```
[[help:dired-mode][your description]]
```

The same procedure can be used for info manuals (as well as many other
buffers that support storing Org links).

Comment: I had forgotten about org-store-link, thanks for the reminder and help. Just for others reading this, keyboard shortcut is C-c l, very similar to insert the link C-c C-l.